# Why am I getting package javax.crypto does not exist

Tags: java, javax.crypto

When I compile a class using `javax.crypto.Mac` I get this error message?

> package `javax.crypto` does not exist

I can fix it by including `jre/lib/jce.jar` in my compile classpath.

Why is `jce.jar` not on the default jdk classpath?  `jre/lib/rt.jar` is on the classpath, and includes other `javax` packages, but jce seems special?

Comment: Just to mention, `jre/lib` path should be in your path anyways. If that was not included then you have not setup java properly on your machine.

Comment: I used the oracle installer.  My version information is  java version "1.7.0_10"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_10-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)

Comment: my colleague has exactly the same problem with openjdk on ubuntu.

Comment: Your title doesn't agree with your question.

Comment: My apologies.  I was compiling with an inherited Ant file, and I did not notice that that the javac task had this specified: bootclasspath="${java.home}/lib/rt.jar".  I will answer the question (as a mistake :) )

Answer (score 23, accepted):

OK, this was a mistake on my part. The Ant file I was using to compile the code had this attribute on the `javac` task:

```
bootclasspath="${java.home}/lib/rt.jar"
```

Doh. You can add the JCE jar like this:

```
bootclasspath="${java.home}/lib/rt.jar:${java.home}/lib/jce.jar"
```

Answer (score 10):

Beware! This class is only included in the jdk from oracle. That means your program won;t be portable among different jdk (eg openjdk)
It is preferable to use this lib externally, it can be downloaded from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-plat-419418.html#JCE-1_2_2-G-JS)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, I downloaded the zip and paste these 3 files into `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\ext` as explained in `jce-1_2_2/jce1.2.2/INSTALL.html` in the zip file.

- `jce1_2_2.jar`
- `US_export_policy.jar`
- `local_policy.jar`

Comment: You should put the full link for the install page.