# javax.crypto with Bndtools

Tags: eclipse, osgi, bndtools, javax.crypto

How am I supposed to be able to use the javax.crypto inside of my Bndtools
project?

I'm trying to compile my project but it seems that Bnd is not able to find
the javax.crypto library.

I'm using Eclipse Juno with Bndtools 2.2 and JDK 7

Comment: Please provide more information, for example show the bnd.bnd file and the specific error message. `javax.crypto` is part of the standard JRE libraries and there is normally no issue with using it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/20619342/23118

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the `javax.crypto` package is imported into your bundle definition. By default, only `java.*` packages are available go OSGi bundles/projects.

Comment: But this is done automatically by bnd(tools). So I don't think it's a runtime classloading issue due to a missing import. Then again the original poster still needs to give details of the error.