# how do I solve this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/SecretKey

Tags: java, exception, htmlunit

How do I solve this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/SecretKey

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.RefreshHandler;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class veriçekmek {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        WebClient web=new WebClient();
        HtmlPage sayfa=web.getPage("http://www.idefix.com");
```

When I run this program I get an error like this

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/SecretKey
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting package javax.crypto does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935447/why-am-i-getting-package-javax-crypto-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javax.crypto package is included in **jce.jar**, which can be found under the "lib" folder of your JRE.
Add it to your classpath, and you should be fine.

For more information about classpath, see:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: How do you run your program?
From command line? From eclipse? Another way?

Comment: Try: right click on the project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jars...

Comment: ı solved this problem.I setup jdk again and It works. :) thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by installing a new reference jdk from https://jdk.java.net.

For whatever reason, these builds include the crypto jars that were missing from the oracle builds.