# Maven build failing because of "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/spec/Sec retKeySpec"

Tags: java, maven, aem, m2e

I am using Eclipse with Maven and trying to deploy a code for my AEM project. But I am getting the below error and my build is getting failed-

```
C:\Documents\Source>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] acs
[INFO] ACS - Core
[INFO] ACS - UI apps
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building acs Snapshot-Release-06-Final
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ acs ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-maven) @ acs ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ acs ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Documents\Source\pom.
xml to C:\.m2\repository\com\acs\web\acs\Snapshot-Release-06-Fi
nal\acs-Snapshot-Release-06-Final.pom
[INFO][INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ACS - Core Snapshot-Release-06-Final
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/common
s/commons-imaging/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] acs ................................................ SUCCESS [  1.566 s]
[INFO] ACS - Core ......................................... FAILURE [  2.216 s]
[INFO] ACS - UI apps ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.444 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-05T22:36:20-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/b
in/../conf/logging/
constituent[1]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/b
in/../lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar
constituent[2]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/b
in/../lib/cdi-api-1.0.jar
constituent[3]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/b
in/../lib/commons-cli-1.4.jar
constituent[4]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/b
in/../lib/commons-io-2.5.jar
constituent[5]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/b
in/../lib/commons-lang3-3.5.jar
constituent[6]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/b
in/../lib/guava-20.0.jar
constituent[7]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/b
in/../lib/guice-4.0-no_aop.jar
constituent[8]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/b
in/../lib/jansi-1.13.jar
constituent[9]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/b
in/../lib/javax.inject-1.jar
constituent[10]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
constituent[11]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
constituent[12]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-artifact-3.5.0.jar
constituent[13]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-builder-support-3.5.0.jar
constituent[14]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-compat-3.5.0.jar
constituent[15]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-core-3.5.0.jar
constituent[16]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-embedder-3.5.0.jar
constituent[17]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-model-3.5.0.jar
constituent[18]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-model-builder-3.5.0.jar
constituent[19]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-plugin-api-3.5.0.jar
constituent[20]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.5.0.jar
constituent[21]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-resolver-api-1.0.3.jar
constituent[22]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.0.3.jar
constituent[23]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-resolver-impl-1.0.3.jar
constituent[24]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-resolver-provider-3.5.0.jar
constituent[25]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-resolver-spi-1.0.3.jar
constituent[26]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-resolver-transport-wagon-1.0.3.jar
constituent[27]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-resolver-util-1.0.3.jar
constituent[28]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-settings-3.5.0.jar
constituent[29]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-settings-builder-3.5.0.jar
constituent[30]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-shared-utils-3.1.0.jar
constituent[31]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/maven-slf4j-provider-3.5.0.jar
constituent[32]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.3.jar
constituent[33]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.3.jar
constituent[34]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/plexus-cipher-1.7.jar
constituent[35]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.7.1.jar
constituent[36]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/plexus-interpolation-1.24.jar
constituent[37]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
constituent[38]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/plexus-utils-3.0.24.jar
constituent[39]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar
constituent[40]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/wagon-file-2.12.jar
constituent[41]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/wagon-http-2.12-shaded.jar
constituent[42]: file:/C:/Maven/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin%20(1)/apache-maven-3.5.0/
bin/../lib/wagon-provider-api-2.12.jar
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/spec/Sec
retKeySpec
        at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:
507)
        at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:
489)
        at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:194)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableCipherSuiteList(SSLConte
xtImpl.java:338)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getDefaultCipherSuiteList(SSLContextI
mpl.java:296)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.init(SSLSocketImpl.java:583)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:547)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryIm
pl.java:109)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnecti
onSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnecti
onSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHtt
pClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.PoolingHtt
pClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainC
lientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainC
lientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.Proto
colExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.Retry
Exec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.Redir
ectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.Internal
HttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.Closeabl
eHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute
(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:834)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInp
utData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:985)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInp
utData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:962)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:12
6)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run
(WagonTransporter.java:569)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTran
sporter.java:436)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get(WagonTranspor
ter.java:413)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRu
nner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:456)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunne
r.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:359)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(Runn
ableErrorForwarder.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExe
cutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:590)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(Basic
RepositoryConnector.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$ResolveTask.
run(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:616)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(Runn
ableErrorForwarder.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$1.execute(De
faultMetadataResolver.java:536)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolve(Defa
ultMetadataResolver.java:391)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolveMetad
ata(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.resolveVe
rsion(DefaultVersionResolver.java:238)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.
loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:232)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.
readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCa
chedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifa
ctDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:528)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDe
pendency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:418)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDe
pendency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(D
efaultDependencyCollector.java:360)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse
(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:513)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDe
pendency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDe
pendency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(D
efaultDependencyCollector.java:360)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDe
pendencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:263)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDepen
dencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:325)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(D
efaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:169)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDe
pendencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resol
veProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAr
eResolved(MojoExecutor.java:246)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre
adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this error?

I got some references here- [ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935447/why-am-i-getting-package-javax-crypto-does-not-exist) and [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935447/why-am-i-getting-package-javax-crypto-does-not-exist), but not sure how to apply them in Maven and eclipse.

Thanks,

Comment: javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec <-- are you using this and did you verify that you properly downloaded and imported the right package to use it?

Comment: I don't think that we are using it. I don't see that anywhere in my project.

Comment: Then it's likely a dependency of something you ARE using. Which likely means a version conflict. You're gonna have to do some research.

Comment: You may not be using it directly in your project but it is used in AEM so if you are compiling code against things like authentication handler API or some plugins from ACS - Commons then it's likely that you are missing dependencies. Try looking up this java class in AEM packages and add the relevant maven dependency. Also, you aren't using openJdk by any chance are you?

Comment: No. not using openJdk.

Comment: The dependency was missing for the jar file. It got resolved but getting a new error now. Hope anyone can help with this-                                                     
------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.20.0:scr (generate-scr-scrdescriptor) on project acs.core: Execution generate-scr-scrdescriptor of goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.20.0:scr failed: Could not load the propery file 'output_xml.properties' for output method 'xml' (check CLASSPATH) -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependency was missing for the jar file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.crypto</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr105-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

After adding the above dependency, the error got resolved.

Comment: Accept this as your own answer so that others know how to fix this issue if they see it.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was due to missing privileges when running Eclipse.
Starting as admin (Win10) solved my issue.